# UIDocumentInteractionController change title of presented view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uidocumentinteraction

I am using the [**`UIDocumentInteractionController`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller) to display PDF files. My files are stored in the filesystem using encoded filenames that are not user-friendly. I do have access to a more friendly name for the file, but the file is not stored with this name (for uniqueness reasons).

When I load the document into the `UIDocumentInteractionController` then the view displays the unfriendly 'real' filename in the title bar.

Is there any way to change the displayed title as presented by the `UIDocumentInteractionController`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`UIDocumentInteractionController` has a `name` property which you can set to your user-friendly name. That name will be used in the title bar of the presented document.

Comment: @RDC Can you show me sample code, as its not working for me.

Comment: This solution does not work. It still shows the file name.

Answer (score 0):

This is Xamarin (C#) code, but I hope it helps anyways

```
public class PreviewFile : IPreviewFile
{
    public PreviewFile()
    {
    }

    public void Preview(string file, string title)
    {
        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        var vc = window.RootViewController;
        bool isUrl = file.StartsWith("file:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        var url = isUrl ? new NSUrl(file) : NSUrl.FromFilename(file);
        
        var controller = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(url);

        controller.Delegate = new MyInteractionDelegate(vc);
        controller.Name = title;


        controller.PresentPreview(true);
    }
}

public class MyInteractionDelegate : UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate
{
    UIViewController parent;

    public MyInteractionDelegate(UIViewController controller)
    {
        parent = controller;
    }

    public override UIViewController ViewControllerForPreview(UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
    {
        return parent;
    }
}
```